# Not getting the dynamically checkbox id on a button click in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

Here I am generating the `check boxes` dynamically, on a button click and I want the checked checkbox ifd on another button click, but I am not getting this id

```
foreach (var item in ip1)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();

    chk = new CheckBox();
    img = new Image();
    lbl.Text = "<br/>";
    // chk.AutoPostBack=true;
    chk.ID = item;
    chk.Text = "UA"+a;
    // chk.Text = "allot";
    chk.CheckedChanged +=chk_Click;

    img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/img.png";
    img.Width = Convert.ToInt32("50");
    img.Height = Convert.ToInt32("50");
    pop.Controls.Add(img);
    pop.Controls.Add(chk);
    if (a % 6 == 0)
        pop.Controls.Add(lbl);

    // ViewState["bbbb"] = pop;
    // chk=(CheckBox)ViewState["xxx"];

    a++;
}
```

Comment: please any body help..m stuck with it

Comment: Please re-read your question and try to make it clearer. You are likely not receiving any responses because we do not understand what you are trying to do.